# Is there a 2-channel 16bit CVPixelBuffer type?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, quartz-graphics

I am not able to find any CVPixelBuffer integer type which could hold 2-component pixel values; where each component is 16bit (signed or unsigned).
bpp = 32
bpc = 16
components = 2

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CVPixelFormatDescriptionRef/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this one? I'm not sure what you need: integer or float type...

```
kCVPixelFormatType_TwoComponent32Float
32 bit two component IEEE float, 32-bit little-endian samples.
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CVPixelFormatDescriptionRef/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Pixel_Format_Types

Comment: I said "signed"/"unsigned", referring to integer formats. Anyway, i added Integer in the description too.